# CSS not working in Django admin: The resource from [css file url] was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Tags: css, django, django-admin, pythonanywhere

Django admin is displaying without CSS because of the error: 
`The resource from “my-website-address/static/admin/css/responsive.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

The CSS url I can open in my browser and it looks fine.

What can I do to fix CSS displaying for standard Django admin interface?

Comment: Just to double-check -- you tagged this with [pythonanywhere], is your site running on the PythonAnywhere hosting service?

Comment: @GilesThomas yes, my website is hosted on Pythonanywhere. But I do not know: is it a hosting related problem or something wrong in my Django project.

Comment: OK -- did you set up the static files mapping based on the help page at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles ?

Comment: @GilesThomas yes, I did. Static files setup was done a long time ago (and I did not make changes after that) and Django admin CSS was displaying fine until now. As proof of correct setup, I can open these CSS files in my browser by typing the URL like "https://my-website-address.com/static/admin/css/base.css"

Comment: @GilesThomas I fixed the problem. My CSS path was mapped to "  /home/[my-username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/" (to python 3.6 folder).
Now I changed in the path "3.6" to "3.7" and the CSS displaying (no error about `mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options`). 
But I still do not know why path to python 3.6 worked before and why it started to raise the error about `mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`.

Comment: It sounds like this might be something pretty specific to the setup of your account on PythonAnywhere -- maybe drop us a line (I work there) at support@pythonanywhere.com and we'll be able to help more easily.  Include your username in the email, and if you're happy for us to look at your files (which we can see from our admin interface, but don't look at without permission) then let us know that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the error

> Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.

because one of my Cloudflare manually created firewall rules blocked CSS URLs.
I discovered this when opened my Cloudflare dashboard and sow that firewall rule was applying 'JS challenge' to the URLs like `https://[my-website]/static/admin/css/`.

So if your website can not load some resources and you get the error about `MIME type` please check your Cloudflare dashboard or try to temporary disable it.

Answer (score 1):

in case a google traveler arrives here: in my case the problem was I forgot to call to "collectstatic" after a big django upgrade in production (apache + django 3.2, from 2.2)

Bests, José.-